# How do you count business days in SSRS between to dates while excluding holidays?

Tags: reporting-services, expression

How do you count business days in SSRS, between two dates, while excluding holidays?

Comment: Could you clarify holidays? Do you mean weekends or bank holidays?

Comment: Business days -  an official work day of the week; In general, days between and including Monday through Friday, and do not include public holidays and weekends

Answer (score 0):

To achive this within SSRS, go to the report code window and add the below

```
Function getBusinessDaysCount(ByVal tFrom As Date, ByVal tTo As Date) As Integer
    Dim tCount As Integer
    Dim tProcessDate As Date = tFrom
    For x as Integer= 1 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, tFrom, tTo) + 1
      If Not (tProcessDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or tProcessDate.DayOfWeek = 
 DayOfWeek.Sunday) Then
        tCount = tCount + 1
      End If
      tProcessDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, tProcessDate)
     Next
     Return tCount
 End Function
```

In the textbox where you need to display the value, add the below expression

=Code.getBusinessDaysCount(parameters!StartDate.Value,parameters!EndDate.Value)
It is assumed the you want to pass the two days from parameters named Startdate and EndDate. If not, modify the expression with required values.

To assist with data integrity You may wish to first check for is nothing. ie:
=IIF(Fields!stared_dt.Value is nothing,"",Code.getBusinessDaysCount(parameters!StartDate.Value,parameters!EndDate.Value))